# What am I doing wrong in my powerpc assembly program?

Tags: assembly, linker, qemu, powerpc

I put together a simple assembly program to familiarize myself with QEMU. I have been following these two tutorials (opensourceforu.efytimes.com/2011/07/qemu-for-embedded-systems-development-part-2/) (http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~mburrel/stuff/ppc-asm.html) Below is the assembly program I wrote for the PowerPC slightly modified from the second tutorial.

```
.global _Start
_Start:
addi 3, 0, 0xa #load 0xA into r3
addi 4, 0, 0xb #load 0xB into r4
addi 5, 0, 0xc #load 0xB into r5
b .
```

It's basic, just loads random values into general registers 3-5.

When I cross compile it I use the following linker script.

```
ENTRY(_Start)
SECTIONS
{
. = 0x10000;
startup : { dummyStartup.o(.text)}
}
```

I put everything together using a cross compiler for ppc via the instructions in the first tutorial and when I run in QEMU, register 3-5 have the expected values.

My problem is when I change 0x10000 to something different, say 0x10500 or 0x9999, the program still runs just fine. The tutorial states that QEMU's -kernel option needs everything to be at 0x10000 in order for my code to get executed, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Why is this?

Comment: I **guess** it will load your code at `0x10000` no matter what, and if you have any memory references they won't work if your code does not expect that address. Of course this code has no memory accesses, so it is position independent.

Comment: Is 0x10000 a standard or is that an implementation decision by qemu? Because I think that's odd that it ignores my supplied address.

Comment: I'll can remove it, I thought since c translates into assembly it should be included.

Comment: @Jester is correct that the test code you wrote is position independent and can be relocated anywhere. A more complex program may not necessarily be position independent. For example if you do a branch absolute ba to a label in your program and the linker sets the origin point wrong the absolute address for the branch will not branch where you think it will.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `0x10000` value is platform dependent. So depending on which machine QEMU is emulating the kernel load address is different.

If you look for `KERNEL_LOAD_ADDR` in the QEMU source you'll see there's several different values:

https://github.com/qemu/qemu/search?q=KERNEL_LOAD_ADDR